# Multiple jQuery events in $(function () { ... only the first one works

Tags: jquery

I have multiple .click() events for my page, but only the first one executes as expected.

```
$(function () {
    $("#delete").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("span.hconf").show();
    })
    $("#div_conf_true").live("click", function () {
        $.post("/u:" + $("span.username").text() + "/delete/"), {
            url_id: $("#div_conf_true").attr("u"),
            uname: $("span.username").text(),
            complete: window.location.reload(true)
        }
    })
    $("#div_conf_false").live("click", function () {
        $("span.hconf").hide();
        $("#delete").show();
    })
})
```

Originally the #div_conf_* events were .click(function (){ events, but I read that any DOM changes will unbind these handlers, so I tried .live, but it still didn't work. What do I need to do in this script to make all three click events accessible through DOM changes?

I am new to jQuery so pardon if this has an obvious answer.

---

**Edit:** Neither the second nor third .click() events work. I have implemented the syntax and indentation corrections suggested by responders, but still no change. The code block above is everything within my script tag. Do I need to wrap the block in something else? Is it an issue with $document.ready()? Am I using .live() incorrectly? Is it the wrong method choice here? I have no errors in the Chrome JS console.

My main concern is that the third .click() function should, to my understanding, simply reverse the effect of the first .click() function, which operates as expected. I have pasted the relevant HTML below.

```
<div id='modify'><a class='modify' id="edit" href='{{ edit_url }}'>edit</a> | <a class='modify' id="delete" u="{{ i.id }}" href='#'>delete</a><span class='hconf' style="display:none">Are you sure? <a class='confirm' id='del_conf_true' href='#'>yes</a> | <a class='confirm' id='del_conf_false' href='#'>no</a></span></div>
```

---

**Edit2:** I have updated the second .click() function, but still no change in functionality.

```
$("#div_conf_true").live("click", function ( {
$.post("/u:"+$("span.username").text()+"/delete/", 
        {
            url_id:$("#div_conf_true").attr("u"), 
            uname:$("span.username").text()
        },
        function() {window.location.reload(true);}
    );
    })
```

Comment: you forgot your semicolons after click() and live().

Comment: @JoeGreen: [semicolons are optional](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptsyntax.php) in javascript (see syntax heading on that page).

Comment: @BradChristie: but treating semicolons as optional is not advisable!

Comment: @Zack, I'm from a c background, semicolons are of the norm. And more often I tend to catch myself using them even when they're not necessary; err, wait();. ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem after re-reading the Google Javascript API docs, and realizing that I had not implemented the google.setOnLoadCallback() into my script. While there were some issues with the code, the code was not causing the larger problem I was seeking to address here.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function () {
    $("#delete").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("span.hconf").show();
    })
    $("#div_conf_true").live("click", function () {
        $.post("/u:" + $("span.username").text() + "/delete/"), { // <-. remove ) here
            url_id: $("#div_conf_true").attr("u"),                //   |
            uname: $("span.username").text(),                     //   |
            complete: window.location.reload(true)                //   |
        }                                                         // <-' and place here
    })
    $("#div_conf_false").live("click", function () {
        $("span.hconf").hide();
        $("#delete").show();
    })
})
```

That line is your problem, remove the `)` after your `/delete/`, otherwise you're closing out the `.post()`. Then place it **after** the brace on the highlighted line.

Comment: And also move down that `)` after the closing `}` of the `$.post`.

Comment: Because the page that is being modified is a display of database objects, and I want to update the page after deletion. After the DB object is deleted, I have to update the page in order to re-run the backend logic. I know there is a better way to do this vice a simple reload but that's pretty low on my priorities atm.

Comment: @mattdeboard: Ah, to each his own. And as an aside, if you use Firefox, ctrl+shift+j is your friend.

Comment: I'm using Chrome but yeah same concept. Thanks for your help, though it did not solve my issue unfortunately. The third .click() event, which should just flip-flop the effects of the second, does not work either.

Comment: @mattdeboard: Just missed it, you have a mis-splaced parenthesis. Place the one you removed on the `}` that lines up with the `$.post` indent. -- I'll update my answer as well.